# Do I need to manually map every emoji UTF number to their respective keyword or is there some sort of standardized JSON for this?

Tags: javascript, emoji, emoticons

Okay so I'm making a chat application and I was able to figure out how to create my own custom emoticons by creating a JSON file like this:

```
[
    {
        keyword: "LOL",
        url: "urlOfImage1"
    },
    {
        keyword: "haha",
        url: "urlOfImage2"
    }
]
```

and whenever a message is sent, I forEach the emote list and replace the words in the message that match any of the keywords with an image that serves as my custom emoticon.

```
        insertEmoticons(message){

            let emotes = [
                {
                    keyword: "LOL",
                    url: "urlOfImage1"
                }
            ]

            emotes.forEach(emote => {
                message = message.replace(emote.keyword, `<span class="${emote.keyword}"><img src="${emote.url}"></span>`)
            })

            return message

        }
```

This works all fine and dandy, however, now I'm wondering if I'm supposed to use the same approach for all UTF emoticons. Do I need to create my own JSON and the map the UTF code - U+1F600 with the keyword - :D for every single emoticon?

I really doubt that's the correct way to do it for 2 reasons.

1. I have no clue what sort of keyword should I use for most emoticons
2. That would mean different platforms ( Twitch, Facebook, Apple,
   Google ) would have to agree on what the keyword would be for every
   specific emoticon, otherwise keyword :) might be a smiling emoticon
   on 1 platform and laughing emoticon on another one. Obviously we all
   know that :) is probably a smiling emoticon, however, there are many
   more emoticons which are a lot vaguer.

Comment: Why not just allow utf-8, like here . Browsers are emoji ready anyway.  If you want alterative emoji for a smiley, then just use a map with a emoji  as the key..  IOW: there is already a standard naming, the emoji itself..

Comment: You know how a lot of people are used to typing :) and they know it will turn into a smiling face. I wanna achieve that, however, just typing :) doesn't do anything.

Comment: No, I'm on mobile and just used the virtual ⌨️, but if you wanted to make things really easy for your users you could put buttons with the icons on to place them in your chat app.